# Getting DataGrid row details

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a quick question regarding getting a specific value from a data grid, say I've got 4 columns, id surname, firstname and phone number. I want to get the ID From the selected row that the user has currently selected ? how would I go around this, I've tried several attempts but it's just returning the whole row rather than the single ID.

Thanks again

Rolls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
((class)yourGrid.SelectedItem).ID
```

In "class" put class of your object stored in grid.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the index of the id column you can get DataGridCell using code at:

[Programmatically edit a datagrid cell in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8147414/programmatically-edit-a-datagrid-cell-in-wpf/8147754#8147754)

Then you can get ID by getting DataSource for DataGridCell.